# Selenium get session ID of new window - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using Selenium in order to perform some checks on Chrome.
I'm automatically browsing to "chrome://flags/#enable-quic" and there in the drop down I (automatically) choose "Enable".
As written below, one has to relaunch in order for the changes to take effect.
I want to open a new tab on the new re-launched window to do some more stuff.

A snip of the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("chrome://flags/#enable-quic")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='enable-quic']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div[2]/select/option[2]").click() #Select "Enable"
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='flagsTemplate']/div[5]/button").click() #Click relaunch
time.sleep(5)
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.gmail.com');")  #Exception after this line
```

The exception I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed
```

Someone has an idea how to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clicking `"Refresh"` button you get new `Chrome` window. You should try to switch to that window before executing `JavaScript`:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("chrome://flags/#enable-quic")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='enable-quic']//select[@class='experiment-select']/option[2]").click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='experiment-restart-button']").click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.gmail.com');")
```

Answer (score 2):

re-launching Chrome is a bad idea because Chromedriver has a reference to the original chrome process.

> `no such window: window was already closed`

so... `browser` is still pointing to the old window.

Instead of trying to relaunch Chrome, just set the option when you create a Chromedriver instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-quic')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```